# Covert a tuple inside list in list to a list

Tags: python

I have a list inside a list (with a tuple inside) in the form:

```
result = [([1,2,3],4),([7,8,9],10)]
```

I want my result to be `[[1,2,3,4],[7,8,9,10]]`. I am using python 2.7. Is there any solution how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `map`

```
>>> result = [([1,2,3],4),([7,8,9],10)]
>>> list(map(lambda x: x[0]+[x[1]] , result))
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Or using list comprehension

```
>>> [x[0]+[x[1]] for x in result]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you unpack each tuple in `result` into a `lst, val` pair, you can just do `lst + [val]` for each one:

```
result = [lst + [val] for lst, val in result]
```